# Visual Studio Team Services not deploying some files

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, web-deployment

This certainly seems to be a bug in Visual Studio Team Services, but I thought I'd share this with the Hive Mind and see if I'm the only one whom is having this problem.

I am using https://manage.windowsazure.com to host the site and deploy from Visual Studio Team Services. All of the other files in the solution seem to go where they are intended, but I have two folders & html files that don't.

in my web project I see that the file is properly listed.

```
<Content Include="App\views\member\profile.html" />
<Content Include="App\views\plants\edit.html" />
<Content Include="App\views\responses\list.html" />
```

The file also appears as it is expected to in the Solution Explorer, Source Code Explorer & VS Team Services.
[image]

However it does NOT appear in the deployed location, and if I look in the new "Monaco" dev tool for Team Services, it is not there.

[image]

I tried to manually add the file into Monaco, but as expected, on subsequent deployments, that file and folder is wiped out.

I thought this might have been a case of not recognizing a pending change, but I renamed the folder and still no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out the solution. What I realized was happening was that The deployments stopped working period, not just certain files were not coming across. This is absolutely a bug in Azure deployment as near as I can figure. I had to drop & recreate my site in the cloud and the deployment continued to work.

As a side rant. Microsoft makes it extremely painful for someone to submit a bug as compared to other software vendors. And they wonder why their market share is shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these files are not set to be copied. In that case they would have something like the following added to their XML:

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've adjusted the properties of both of those missing files to CopyToOutputDirectory Always in the property window (although none of the other html files have this set). Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you aren't seeing the wrong slot in your Cloud Service.  Each Service has a Staging and Production slot - the CI deploy from VS Team Services for Azure typically deploys to the Staging slot only.  See: http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/02/28/the-purpose-of-the-staging-deployment-slot/